# Flutter android build failed

Tags: android, gradle, build, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I add cloud_firestore plugin to my flutte project, then I get this error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'com.android.support:support-media-compat' has different version for the compile (26.1.0) and runtime (27.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and the solution was to add this block :

```
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
```

to **android**/**build.gradle** file

Comment: Where should I use this?
Like end of file?

Answer (score -1):

At the end of android/build.gradle file, add below lines:

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```